# condition in criteria in yii framework php

Tags: php, mysql, yii

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with = array('reviewCount', 'category10', 'category20', 'category30', 'town');
$criteria->select = 't.id,business,street,postalCode,contactNo,checkinCount,count(tbl_abc.id) as spcount';
$criteria->join = 'left join tbl_abc on t.id=tbl_abc.businessId';
$criteria->group = 't.id';
$criteria->order = 'spcount DESC';
$criteria->condition='spcount>1';
$bizModel = new CActiveDataProvider(Business::model(), array(
    'criteria' => $criteria
));
```

I'm getting this error:

`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'spcount' in 'where clause'`

If I omit the condition the query works fine & orders businesses by spcount. So how do I rewrite this query such that I get all the businesses whose spcount is greater than 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't reference aliases in a `WHERE` part ([proof link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)). Remove the condition line and add the following:

```
$criteria->having = 'COUNT(tbl_abc.id) > 1';
```

**UPDATE**

[`CActiveDataProvider` accepts finder instance](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider#__construct-detail), so you'll need a model scope:

```
<?php
class Business extends CActiveRecord
{
  public function scopes()
  {
    return array(
      'hasSpcount' => array(
        'with' => array('reviewCount', 'category10', 'category20', 'category30', 'town'),
        'select' => 't.id,business,street,postalCode,contactNo,checkinCount,count(tbl_abc.id) as spcount',
        'join' => 'left join tbl_abc on t.id=tbl_abc.businessId',
        'group' => 't.id',
        'order' => 'spcount DESC',
        'having' => 'COUNT(tbl_abc.id) > 1',
      ),
    );
  }
}

// usage
$provider = new CActiveDataProvider(Business::model()->hasSpcount());
```

Hope this works

Comment: having is doing the job. But there is one problem with that. $bizModel->getTotalItemCount() is 613 which is actually the total number of records ignoring the filter spcount>1. But otherwise its showing the filtered results. Because Im using Clistview so its creating a problem in pagination. Its showing pagination for 7pages when it has only 7-8 records.

Comment: @iThink You can't rewrite `getTotalItemCount` to apply filter?

Comment: Look without using filter i.e $criteria->having='spcount>1' getTotalItemCount =163. And using filter getTotalItemCount should be 8 because its showing 8 records but getTotalItemCount is 163

Comment: `getTotalItemCount` has something like `SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt ...` ? Could you post the SQL which is used in this method

Comment: I think you didnt get my last problem. The filtering is working fine. But the value of getTotalItemCount is not the filtered number of records.May be Yii count works differently for "having". Thats why for  clistview pagination I'm getting wrong number of pages

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a sub-select-query.

For example in the select part of you criteria object:

```
$criteria->select = 't.id,business,street,postalCode,contactNo,checkinCount,(select count(id) from tbl_abc where t.id=businessId) as spcount';
```

Or as an inner join (which can also contain the "where spcount>1" condition):

```
$criteria->join = 'join (select businessId, count(*) as spcount from tbl_abc) abc on t.id=abc.businessId and abc.spcount>1';
```

In both scenarios spcount is also alvailable in the where-clause of your query. Also, "group by t.id" is not necessary anymore since spcount is now a single value for each row of the main table ("t").

Hope this helps