# Yii Find Condition with Custom Field

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm trying to find a `Question` that have custom field `userAnswered` equal `0`.

I cannot figure out wheres the problem.

---

Code:

```
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with='answers';
    $criteria->select='*, count(answers.id) as userAnswered';
    $criteria->condition='userAnswered=:userAnswered';
    $criteria->params=array(':userAnswered'=>0);
    $model=Question::model()->find($criteria);
```

---

Question Model:

```
class Question extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $userAnswered;

...

public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'answers' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Answer', 'answer_id'),
    );
}
```

---

Yii Error Returned:

```
SQL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'userAnswered' in 'where clause'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: [condition in criteria in yii framework php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839978/condition-in-criteria-in-yii-framework-php)

Code:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with='answers';
$criteria->select='*, count(answers.id) as userAnswered';
$criteria->having='userAnswered=0';
$model=Question::model()->find($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

Question has a HAS_MANY connection with Option. When you perform a select from Question with Option you are actually running 2 selects, 1 to bring the Question details, the second to bring over the options.

You are doing a `SELECT FROM Question WHERE criteria_conditions` + a `SELECT FROM Option WHERE ...`

So you cannot put a condition in the criteria on anything related from Option because it will fail on the first select.

You have 2 options now:
1) to use `$criteria->together = true;` Read more here http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/280/1-n-relations-sometimes-require-cdbcriteria-together/
2) To create the criteria condition something like 
$items = Something::model()->with(array('relationname'=>array('condition'=>'')))->find...

I am not sure if the second one will work but it should, I already use 'order'=> to order the records, I believe 'condition' should also work.

The 2 options might produce different results so make sure you use the one that you need.

Comment: I tried to add `$criteria->together = true;` but still returning the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use aliased columns in a WHERE clause.

You have to use :

```
$criteria->condition = 'count(userOptions.id) =:userAnswered';
```

Comment: Hi @kumar_v! Anyway I'm getting error `SQL: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function.` trying to use like that.

Comment: I just comment `condition` and `params` lines and added this one, in the original code.

Comment: you have to pass params. Please try by uncommenting the params line.

Comment: I found the problem! I need to use `having` instead `condition`.