# (Yii)CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I'm trying to execute this sql query but an exception occurs...I tried the query in PhpMyAdmin and it worked ok.

```
<?php
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->condition='select min(purchase_order_id) from purchase_order where purchase_order_id >'.$model->purchase_order_id;
        $nextfield = \POrder::model()->model()->findAll($criteria);
           ?>
```

The exception is,
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select min(purchase_order_id) from purchase_order where purchase_order_id >65' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM `purchase_order` `t` WHERE select min(purchase_order_id) from purchase_order where purchase_order_id >65

Comment: It was a wrong post sorry...But still I think it's not the where clauses.

Comment: I believe the idea is that `$criteria->condition` is used to [build the where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839978/condition-in-criteria-in-yii-framework-php), not specify the entire query.

Comment: What can i do to execute my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the result of the query, do the following:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("
SELECT MIN(purchase_order_id) FROM purchase_order
WHERE purchase_order_id > :purchase_order_id
")->queryScalar(array('purchase_order_id'=>$model->purchase_order_id'));
```

That will return exactly the single value that you would get from phpmyadmin or mysql workbench.

If you want the model record which corresponds to that purchase_order_id, then you can do the following:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addCondition("t.purchase_order_id = (
SELECT MIN(purchase_order_id)
FROM purchase_order
WHERE purchase_order_id > :previous_purchase_order_id)");
$criteria->params['previous_purchase_order_id'] = $model->purchase_order_id;
$nextfield = \POrder::model()->model()->find($criteria);
```

I'm assuming that there is only one such model, so I changed the `findAll` to `find`.